# URL to VF Page to INCLUDE Header and Sidebar

Tags: visualforce, sidebar, header

I hope this isn't a dup, I can't seem to find it if it is. I have an inline VF page in a standard account detail page. A button in my VF page does a pagereference redirect to another (managed) VF page. I have to specify "_top" as my target in my form tag to get to the parent container, but the second VF page shows without the header and sidebar, because I'm calling it with a URL directly.

Are there any parameters that I could add to my URL to make the second page open WITH sidebar and headers as if I were calling the second page from a standard SFDC page?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you'll just have to move the markup into a component and then create two separate pages, one with header, one without.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use an `iframe`?

Create a new VF page that doesn't hide header and sidebar and host your second page within an `iframe`

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:iframe src="URL_TO_YOUR_PAGE"/>
</apex:page>
```

I think that this solution should cover most use cases as with little additional effort you could make this page accept some custom parameters from a link calling it, and then just pass those parameters to your `src` url inside `iframe` if needed.

Comment: Creative solution @smukov! I'm going to see if there are any other suggestions that may not require an additional page, but this can certainly be a viable option. I'll mark as answer if I go this route. Thanks.